# Update bare repo mirror preserving own branches

Tags: git

I have my own GIT server, in which I did a 'bare clone' of a public repo.
Let's call PUB the public repo, and LOC the bare clone on my own server.
I use LOC as remote for developing, creating my own branches that are not present in PUB.
Then I push my branches to LOC.

I want to fetch any new content from PUB to LOC but I do not want any of my own branches to be pushed from LOC to PUB.

I can do none operation on PUB since it is out of my control. I can do any operation on LOC instead.

For the purposes I described I have a script, run every night, that executes:

```
git --git-dir ${LOC_PATH} remote update --prune
```

If I clone PUB to LOC using

```
git clone --mirror <remote_repo>
```

then at the script execution my own branches are erased from LOC.

If I clone PUB to LOC using

```
git clone --bare <remote_repo>
```

then the script seems to fetch successfully PUB to LOC (that's what the command output suggests); but observing LOC content with a browser or fetching LOC to my PC I don't see in the log any new commit that I know to be present in PUB.

Reading the answers on other stackoverflow questions, it seems that the right command is:

```
git --git-dir ${LOC_PATH} fetch --all
```

but at present time I stick to `git ... remote update ...` since it should do an implicit `fetch` operation.

Is there any solution for **automatically** keep up to date this quirky form of mirroring?

I looked at:

- [Mirror git repo into new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66732984/mirror-git-repo-into-new-branch)
- [How do you update a bare repo from a remote source using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131664/how-do-you-update-a-bare-repo-from-a-remote-source-using-git)
- [How to keep all branches and tags in sync in a fork or mirror repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918635/how-to-keep-all-branches-and-tags-in-sync-in-a-fork-or-mirror-repo)
- [How do I update my bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382679/how-do-i-update-my-bare-repo)

and some other sites found on internet. Obviously I found no viable solution.

Comment: You know the correct way is to use `git fetch` yet you keep doing something else, knowing it is the wrong way. And now you want us to help you... do what? Did I summarize your question correctly or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: @friedrich, you are close to the truth when you say that I am doing something else knowing it is the wrong way.  :-)
The man page of `git-remote` reports that the `update` command `Fetch updates for remotes or ...`.
So, just before moving from `remote update` to `fetch`, I would like that someone explain me why `update remote` does not _fetch_ (that is what I expect).

Answer (score 0):

I checked on my machine with some repos and came to the following conclusions:

- `git remote update` indeed performs an implicit `fetch` and ...
- `git fetch` alone won't work for the problem, either.

After any of the above operations, `FETCH_HEAD` is created and points to the newest commit on the public remote (called PUB in the question). As your local repo (called LOC) is a bare one, it is not possible to `merge` or `pull` on it. When `pull`ing from LOC, the newest commits are just not there.

The brute force solution to apply `FETCH_HEAD` is to simply `git reset --soft FETCH_HEAD` on LOC. Afterwards, you will see all the new commits.

The other solution (as mentioned in [the answer to How do I update my bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382703/796259)) is to use `git fetch *:*` in the first place. I could not find a way to pass `*:*` to `git submodule update` but maybe there is one.

As mentioned in the comments, `git clone`'s `--mirror` option does exactly what it's supposed to do: it *mirrors* the remote. Any additional branches or commits are thrown out. So this is good for backups but bad if you want to have something that's not an exact replica.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich for the clarification. Now I got the point.